# replace special characters from string

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to replace some characters with another one with special condition.
like

so if

```
a string contains _ is then replace it with .
a string contains __ is then replace it with _ (remove single _ multiple _ )
a string starting with # then replace it with $
a string starting with ## then replace it with #
```

I have tried

```
str_replace('_', '.', $string);
```

but it replace all _ to . I don't want to replace all _ I just want to replace only single located  _ like ('4__69' gives 4..69)

Comment: Generally you have to try doing it before it will happen...

Comment: So we are there to do your homework?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: try first yourself and if you face an issue then ask here :)

Comment: I have tried with str_replace() function but it's difficult for me, I am new to php

Comment: @Progi1990 `str_replace` is the correct function. You should read the docs for starting to use PHP, there are plenty out there.

Comment: @Progi1990 you tried with str_replace(), mention here in question whatever you tried.

Comment: *"a string starting with #"*  -  the string needs to be in the beginning of the line?

Comment: @PedroLobito, yes just a normal string like '#abc' need to converted by '$abc' but if '##abc' => '#abc' and '###abc'=>'##abc' and so on same with _

Comment: Please post samples of the desired **output**

Comment: @PedroLobito
input string => output string
    a_bc=>a.bc
    a__ab=>a_bc
    a___bc=>a__bc

Comment: @PedroLobito, first of all I need to replace 'a.bc' to 'a_bc' just because the key can not contain . and key can't start with $ so, I applied this solution
for saving 'a.bc' replace this key to 'a_bc' and while retrieving key from mongodb a_bc will be replace by a.bc

Comment: @PedroLobito, but here is one problem I just noticed. while storing key into mongo if key is a_.bc then what should I am going to store it in mongodb by my rule It will be a___bc because 1st two __ were for single _  and second _ for . then how can I convert original string while fetching from mongodb

Comment: any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

use array with key and value and in foreach loop user str_replace function to replace key with value

```
$string_spe = array("__"=>"_","_"=>".","##"=>"#","#"=>"$");

$string_val ="__HI This is me";
foreach($string_spe as $key => $value){
 $string_val =str_replace($key,$value,$string_val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example we have:

```
<?php
$text = "Hello, asd!"; //Random text
$var = str_replace("asd", "qwe", $text); //Replacing 'asd' with 'qwe' everywhere
echo $var;
?>
```

The above will replace 'asd' with 'qwe' and will output:

```
Hello, qwe!
```

---

Another example:

```
<?php
$text = "Hello, JOHNasd123!"; //Random text - note 'asd' is in the middle of the string
$var = str_replace("asd", "qwe", $text); //Replacing 'asd' with 'doe' everywhere
echo $var;
?>
```

And the second example will replace 'asd' which is in the middle of the string with 'doe' and will output:

```
Hello, JOHNdoe123!
```

---

For the second question you should use:

```
str_replace("__", ".", $string); //Note that the underlines '__' are two!
```

> **Note:**
>        str_replace($symbolToBeReplaced, $replacingSymbol, $variable);
>   Also works with numbers and all kind of strings and etc.